# How can I place 3 objects next to each other in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, text

I want to place the image and the 2 texts next to each other. With the first text being at the far left. The image being directly in the center. And the last text being at the far right. Here is what I currently have...

```
<body>

<h2><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">MrEpicGaming4U</font></h2>
<img src="website_art.png" height= "75" width= "235"/>
<h2><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">The Art of Gaming</font></h2>

</body>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Add {float:left} to everyone(h2, img) tags

Comment: Use float:left and float:right on left and right elements(texts) respectively.

Comment: I didn't see image width was fixed. Better to use float:left on both h2 and img. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You don't close the font element in the right place in your HTML code.

Besides, is a good practice to have the style in a external file (I talk about the CSS).

Change for this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>MrEpicGaming4U</h2>
        <img src="Your url" height="75" width="235"/>
        <h2>The art of gaming</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Put these CSS rules:

```
h2 {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    color: #9C0;
}

.container > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I would go as far as to say the HTML is bad because `<font>` exists at all.  :-)

Comment: @Brad The OP is probably working in an old CMS environment that generates HTML code...

Comment: @user2426533 can you put a jsfiddle?

Comment: Good one but when I add some margin or padding they get arranged in horizontal line

Answer (score 1):

**inline-block**:

```
h2, img{display: inline-block;}
```

**If you are sticking with float:left** then just make the container div with **overflow: hidden** ...no need to add *clear:both* extra div...

Here are both examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/kAVQ3/2/

Answer (score 1):

You don't "need" to add float right on the last item...

```
<h2 style="float:left"><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">MrEpicGaming4U</font></h2>
<img  style="float:left" src="website_art.png" height= "75" width= "235"/>
<h2 style="float:left"><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">The Art of Gaming</font></h2>
```

...but you should clear them once you are done.

```
<hr style="clear:both";>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <h2 style="float:left;"><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">MrEpicGaming4U</font></h2>
   <div style="float:left;"><img src="website_art.png" height= "75" width= "235"/></div>
   <h2 style="float:right;"><font color="#99CC00"><font face="Verdana">The Art of Gaming</font></h2>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```